# Genetic Algorithm, large population vs small one

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

Im wondering if there is a general rule of thumb for population sizing. Ive read in a book that 2x the chromosome length is a good starting point. Am i correct in assuming then that if i had an equation with 5 variables, i should have a population of 10?

Im also wondering if the following is correct:

**Larger Population Size.**

**Pros:**
Larger diversity so more likely to pick up on traits which return a good fitness.

**Cons:**
Requires longer to process.

vs

**Smaller Population Size.**

**Pros:**
Larger number of generations experienced per unit time.

**Cons:**
Mutation will have to be more prominent in order to compensate for smaller population??

**EDIT**

A little additional info, say i have an equation which has 5 unknown parameters. For each parameter i have anywhere between 10-50 values i would like to try assign to each of these variables. So for example

variable1 = 20 different values
variable2 = 15 different values
...

I thought a GA would be a decent approach to such a problem as the search space is quite large, ie worst case for the above would be 312,500,000 permutations (unless i have screwed up?) n!/(n-k)! where n = 50 and k = 1 => 50 * 50 * 50 * 50 * 50

unfortunately the number of parameters/range of values to check can vary alot so i was looking for some sort of rule of thumb as to how large i should set the population.

Thanks for ur help + if there is any more info you need/prefer to discuss in one of the chatrooms, just give me a shout.

Comment: Ive also come up with the 2* rule of thumb myself. See : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7609715/571138

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure where you read that 2x the chromosome length is a good starting point, but I'm guessing it's a book that concentrated on larger problems.

If you only have five variables, a genetic algorithm is probably not the right choice for converging upon a solution. With a chromosome length of five you're probably going to find that you very quickly reach a non-deterministic(this will change in subsequent runs) local minimum and slowly iterate around that space until you find the true local minimum.

However, if you are insistent on using a GA I would suggest abandoning that rule of thumb for this problem and really think about starting population as a measure of how far from the final solution you expect a random solution to be.

The reason that many rule of thumbs is dependent on chromosome length is because that's a decent proxy for this, if I have a hundred variables, and given randomly generating dna sequence is going to be further from ideal than if I had only one variable.

Additionally, if you're worried about computation intensity I'm going to go ahead and say that it shouldn't be an issue since you're dealing with such a small solution set. I think a better rule of thumb for smaller sets like this would be along the lines of:

```
(ln(chromosome_length*(solution_space/granularity)/mutation_rate))^2
```

Probably with a constant thrown in to scale for the particular problem.

It's definitely not a great rule of thumb (no rule is) but here's my logic for it:

- Chromosome length is just a proxy for size of solution space, so taking into account the size of the solution space will necessarily increase the accuracy of this proxy
- A smaller mutation rate necessitates a larger population size to compensate for the fact that you are more prone to get caught in local minima
- Any rule of thumb should scale logarithmically since a genetic algorithm is akin to a tree search of your solution space.
- The squared term was mostly the result of trying this out, but it looks like the logarithmic scaling was a little aggressive, though the general shape seemed right.

However I think a better choice would be to start at a reasonable number (100) and try iterating up and down until you find a population size that seems to balance accuracy with execution speed.

Comment: +1 for 2x the chromosome length not always being a good idea. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @TerryMalone Thanks, I'm playing around with the more reasonable rule of thumb, I'm not quite sure I'm happy with it now though, thoughts?

Comment: I usually go with a similar approach. I mostly use genetic algorithms for parameter estimation and chromosome size usually varies from around 40-100. I haven't found any decent rules of thumb and generally use the approach you mentioned. Since my genetic algorithms are usually carried out hundreds of times spending a couple of days testing different population sizes (as well as other parameters) works well.

Comment: @TerryMalone I tried it out on some examples and I think it was about the square root of a reasonable number.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Ive edited my original question after reading Terry's answer. After reading yours, i have a feeling i may have misunderstood what chromosome length is though?

Comment: No, looks like you understood it correctly, That said, 300 million, despite being a large number is incredibly small for a problem space assuming these are numerical values. It's a different case if they are nominal, but it's comparable to three numbers between 0 and 1 with fairly bad precision. I wouldn't brute force it, but a simple gradient descent or using SLSQP should be fine.

Comment: I hadnt looked into gradient descent before, thanks for broadening my horizons. Yeah brute force is not an option as its taking ~1min to run each permutation using all the computing power i have available. This was one of the reasons i went with GA's. For now ill stick with your equation above since ive nearly finished the GA code, and would like to get some sims running. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: In ur equation, im assuming "solution_space" = 300 mil? What are u referring to with "granularity" though? Thanks again.

Comment: Ah no, in that example your solution space would be 50 and your granularity would be 1 (give or take). Solution space is for one variable in the chromosome. It comes out to about 50. Granularity would be for a numerical categorization where you would say, I'm looking for something in the span of say 1000, but I only really need a granularity of 2 (so 567 and 568 would be treated the same).

Comment: If i have varying lengths of possible values for the inputs, ie parameter1 has 5 values, parameter2 has 100 values, would u choose the larger of the two? Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

As with most genetic algorithm parameters population size is highly dependant on the problem. There are certain factors that can help to point in the direction of whether you should have a large or small population size but a lot of the time testing different values against a known solution before running it on your problem is a good idea (if this is possible of course).

A population size of 10 does seem rather small though. You say you have an equation with five variables. Is your problem represented by a chromosome of 5 values? It seems small for a chromosome and if this is the case it's likely that using a genetic algorithm may not be the best way to solve the problem. Perhaps if you give a bit more detail on your problem and how you are representing it people may have a better idea of how to advise you.

I'd also add that your cons for large and small population sizes aren't exactly correct. A larger population size does take longer to process than a small one but since it can often solve the problem quicker then overall the processing time isn't necessarily longer. gain, it's highly dependant on the problem. With a smaller population size mutation shouldn't have to be more prominent. Mutation is generally used to stop the genetic algorithm from becoming stuck in a local maximum and should usually be a very small value. A small population is more likely to become stuck in a local maximum but if you have a mutation value which is too high you may be nullifying the natural improvement of the genetic algorithm.